# Application Open Triggers

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile

Are there any alternative ways to open an application quickly besides the 2 prominent ones, url extension and screen tap. Possibly using the volume button or homepage button to initiate the app? Android and Apple devices.

Comment: Are you asking this question as a user or a programmer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that Apple doesn't allow you to change the functionality of their buttons from a programmer's standpoint. I think there are some private API's that you could use, though it doesn't matter if you intend on deploying your app because Apple would reject it on that basis. I'll try to find some documentation to back up Apple not allowing button functionality to change, and then I will edit my post.

**EDIT:**
See this question: [Temporarily Lock or Disable iphone home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190169/temporarily-lock-or-disable-iphone-home-button)

They give examples of apps(Camera+) that change button functionality and were pulled from the store when these changes were discovered.

I'm afraid I can't speak for anything on Android, though I wouldn't be surprised if it was similar.

Comment: If you're considering this question closed, be sure to accept an answer :)