# Disable ipad fully

Tags: iphone

Can we disable the ipad fully? I have heard that its not possible. I have searched for it and it shows that the above cannot be done and if its done then the app will be rejected. But still for an accurate answer i'm posting this. Can any one provide me with the correct response?

Comment: pls dont down vote it its just a doubt that i have asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do this without rooting the iPad (thereby invalidating its warrantee) and installing what most users would consider malware. (You may well have a reasonable use case — loaning them out or something — I'm just saying, that's how most users would see it.)

Comment: thanks Crowder for your correct response but can you pls provide any apple approved links that state the above...

Comment: @Kiron: I can't, no, because mostly they don't document things you can't do; they document things you *can* do. But a similar question has been raised many times about disabling the button when someone's in an app (usually this is raised by people writing apps for small children where they want a parent to exit the app, not the child). You can't do that. If you can't do that (without rooting the device), you certainly can't do what you're describing.

Comment: ok thanks Crowder that was a great support for me. Thank you very much..

Comment: @Kiron: No worries, glad that helped. Here's an example of the home button question, the answers may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190169/temporarily-lock-or-disable-iphone-home-button

Comment: the link was just great.... thanks....