# how to disable home button in iPhone programmatically ios7

Tags: iphone, ios7, home-button

I am developing an enterprise app which supports Guided Access i.e disable/enable the home button (like Child Lock) once the app is launched. I have browsed & spend lot of time on this but no use. :( I din't get any helpful info.

Any suggestion or needful information will be helpful for me.

Note: No Jailbreaking

Comment: Do you want to disable iphone's home button?

Comment: You need to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190169/temporarily-lock-or-disable-iphone-home-button

Comment: @Impossible Yes, Any api's that supported by apple.

Comment: Hope this helps you.  http://www.amtelnet.com/mobile-device-management-resources/faq/what-is-apple-ios-kiosk-mode/

Answer (score 3):

You have to turn on Accessibility feature. 
Settings > General > Accessibility > Guided Access
Set Guided Access on.

Now you can triple click the home button and prevent access to the home button.

There is no way on this planet an app can programmatically disable the home button. The iPhone pretty much fails to work without it.

Comment: right. Guided access supports i think ioS6+ ver. iOS Kiosk or Guided accessmode is a feature that allows only one application to run at a time on a mobile device. The main goal of Kiosk mode is to lock a device into a particular application, to either allow an app to take over the screen of a device, such as in-game applications, or to prevent users from opening other applications that should not be accessible to them, such as in retail environments.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

You cannot stop the home button being pressed as this interferes with the navigation and usability of iOS 7.

The only way to force the home button not to work is to get a case which covers it and does not allow it to be pressed.