# disable hardware button ios xdk

Tags: android, ios, intel-xdk

I'm using Intel XDK to dev a multi platform app to Target IOS and Android.

The end user will be using this app in a shop with the tablet on a stand.

I need a way to disable the hardware buttons on the device and replace that functionality within the app. Eg. to quit the app I type my password.

Is this possible using XDK?

What else might I be able to try?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190169/temporarily-lock-or-disable-iphone-home-button

Comment: Based on the link in the comment from @LordT, it does not appear to be possible on iOS. To see if someone has found a solution, search the web for PhoneGap or Cordova plugins that allow you to do what you want. Since the XDK creates Cordova apps, Cordova plugins are the path to such customization. :)